# how to stop ng-repeat in the middle of the repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game and am having issues with the styling. I have a `ng-repeat` for all 9 squares and need to add a div after every 3rd square so that the next row can be built. I'm using `ng-repeat-end` as instructed in the docs but am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<p>Turn: <span ng-bind="vm.turn"></span></p>
<div class="container" ng-repeat="square in vm.squares track by square.id">
    <div class="square" ng-bind="square.piece" ng-click="vm.move(square.id)"></div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end class="row-divider" ng-if="!(square.id % 3)"></div>
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" click="newGame()">New game</button>
```

```
.square {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.row-divider {
  clear: both;
  display:block;
}


angular
.module('app')
.directive('ticTacToe', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'tic-tac-toe.html',
    controller: TicTacToeController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };

TicTacToeController.$inject = [];

function TicTacToeController(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.turn = 0;
  let currentPiece = 'X';
  vm.squares = [
    { id: 1, piece: null },
    { id: 2, piece: null },
    { id: 3, piece: null },
    { id: 4, piece: null },
    { id: 5, piece: null },
    { id: 6, piece: null },
    { id: 7, piece: null },
    { id: 8, piece: null },
    { id: 9, piece: null }
    ];
  vm.move = function(squareId) {
    console.log('click');
    let index = squareId - 1;
    currentPiece = vm.turn % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
    vm.squares[index].piece = currentPiece;
    vm.turn++;
  };
  vm.newGame = function(){
    vm.turn = 0;
  }
};

})
```

Here is the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/XGhX5zVWCjSnn3OaKNQ6?p=preview

Comment: I opened the plunker and showed me the expected soduko model .. whats the problem

Comment: Nevermind i opened a small window ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with `ng-repeat-start`.

See plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/jck226trFWnxGuWNuu02?p=preview

```
<p>Turn: <span ng-bind="vm.turn"></span></p>
<div class="container" ng-repeat-start="square in vm.squares track by square.id">
  <div class="square" ng-bind="square.piece" ng-click="vm.move(square.id)"></div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end class="row-divider" ng-if="!(square.id % 3)"></div>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" click="newGame()">New game</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, glad I could help. It works because ng-repeat-end directive needs to start with `ng-repeat-start`. The normal `ng-repeat` is not implemented to look further than it's in own element. The `ng-repeat-end` element is therefore not in the `ng-repeat` and is added once to the DOM. `square.id % 3 = NaN` when outside `ng-repeat` and !NaN is true in `ng-if` so it's shown once. See the differnt in the respective DOM's  Hope that was enough.

Comment: I see. So if you have ng-repeat-start you have to have ng-repeat-end, too. And vice-a-versa?

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is doing exactly what you coded

First loop creates 9 divs with the square class then second loop comes to make the separaters

Try making only one loop containing 2 divs one for the squares and the other for the separator with `ng-if=!(square.id % 3)`